# Error when I compile an example from Contiki

Tags: contiki

When I run this command on Contiki

```
sudo make TARGET=srf06-cc26xx BOARD=sensortag/cc2650 cc26xx-demo.bin CPU_FAMILY=cc26xx
```

it returns the following error:

> CC        ../../platform/srf06-cc26xx/./contiki-main.c make: arm-none-eabi-gcc: Command not found make: *** [obj_srf06-cc26xx/contiki-main.o] Error 127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run make, if your contiki repo is in a directory with all permissions for your user then you don't need to run it as sudo.
To install the arm-none-eabi-gcc package, then run:

```
    sudo apt-get install arm-none-eabi-gcc
```

After having it installed, you can check what version you have installed:

```
    arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
```

and your output should look something like this (this is for Ubuntu 16.04):

```
    arm-none-eabi-gcc (15:4.9.3+svn231177-1) 4.9.3 20150529 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
    There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I hope it helps!

Br, Virginia

Answer (score 1):

Read the target platform's `srf06-cc26xx` README file: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/platform/srf06-cc26xx

First, you need to install the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain from  https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

If you have it installed, make sure `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is in your `PATH` environmental variable.

You'll also need the `srecord` applications from http://srecord.sourceforge.net (for Linux, there is `srecord` package available via `apt-get`).